# Web service Response got a schema validation error

Tags: web-services, soapui

I'm using glassfish for my development.

When I hit a web service by sending a SOAP request through SoapUI in our UAT box. I got the following schema validation error message.

> Invalid QName value: Can't resolve prefix 'ns0'

The response looks like following for the line causing the error.

```
<faultcode>ns0:SC_018</faultcode>
```

But in my local box. I don't get the validation error. Because the line causing problem above looks like

```
<faultcode xmlns:ns0="http://****.com">ns0:SC_018</faultcode>
```

I'm thinking there should be some JVM options set up are different that may cause this error ?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Where exactly do you see the message `Invalid QName value: Can't resolve prefix 'ns0'`? Also, where the is this `<faultcode>ns0:SC_018</faultcode>` line? In your request or your response?

Comment: In the response I saw this error and <faultcode>ns0:sc_018</faultcode> also in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a namespace prefix `ns0` (in your XML request/response) that is not defined.

Because you say the line appears at one machine with the proper namespace definition (`xmlns:ns0="http://****.com"`) and not at the other, this can be a problem at the service provider.

`ns0:SC_018` looks like a custom fault code that sometimes is built right (with namespace and no error given) and sometimes isn't (no namespace and error appears).

You say this appears in one machine and not at other, is it the same client? SoapUI is a Java program, so it must behave almost exactly at different environments. Also, this is such a specific issue that seems very unlikely this is a JVM configuration problem.

Comment: All the client in my dev machine have no such error, but unlucky for all clients in UAT machine. Coz they are connected to different database so the clients are different.

Comment: SC_018 is the exception type I defined in the exception rule class. I have no idea where the ns0 comes from. The first several lines of response look like as follows   <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode xmlns:ns0="http://***.com">ns0:SC_018</faultcode>

Comment: So they are two services, one works (dev box) and other doesn't (UAT box)? They have the exact same implementation, except for their database url?

Comment: Same project has been deployed on the glassfish of both machine. The only difference is the database connection

Comment: What about the clients, are they the same? (You can also use a tool like [TCPMon](http://technonstop.com/tcpmon-tutorial) to check what are the actual sent and received XMLs).

Comment: @user1311839 so, did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue, you have update the schema, once schema is updated successfully, then try to update the definition. It would be fixed.